# Cannot use register while in visual mode in vscode vim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, vsvim

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but while in visual mode, typing `"` and follow with register name will quit the command for some reason, like `v"a`.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with `v"a` to begin with. That command is meaningless in actual Vim so who knows how it is handled in a limited Vim emulator?

Comment: At first I'm trying to do `v"ay` command which do visual mode and copy them to a register `a`. From googling that seems to be the way to do it, but the command in vscode just cut it off first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a problem but the command works just fine, only that the display got cut off first. Posted an [issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/7621#issue-1198897373).